# VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: windows, php, web-hosting, xampp, virtual-memory

I keep getting the following error in my PHP error text for Xampp on Windows 10. Using WordPress as the CMS.

Feeling like I have tried everything but hoping there is at least one person here that can solve it.

I have tried changing the INI and Conf setting. Changing WordPress config file memory limits. Checking the disk. Resetting some netsh winsock thing. Disabled plugins. Changed a registry setting that was supposed to allow for more a bigger resource area for RAM to be allocated.

Really need this to work and it was for weeks then this error starting appearing. I know Xampp is not really for production but this website is the only thing that feeds my family and I can't fund a cloud server again.

Doing basic monitoring using Task Manager, the size of the the Apache HTTP process rarely gets to even 1GB. I have a good SSD with like 50 GB free and 16GB of RAM. The error appears usually after about 20 mins and then the website will be ERROR 500.

```
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address
```